# How can I add security header in message?

Tags: java, soap

I wanto to built a simple soap client in JAVA to call a soap JAVA web service.
So I have import WSDL in my project ad built the client. So if I try to run my code, I have this erro:

> AVVERTENZA: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
>   AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}InvalidSecurity
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: ERROR: No security header found in the message
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:ERROR: No security header found in the message
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117).........

The problem is:

> ERROR: No security header found in the message

How can I fixed this problem?

EDIT::

this is the code thai I use:

```
String keyStorePath = "C:\\Users\\michele.castriotta\\Desktop\\Certificati\\keystore_healthnetbr.jks";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(is, "changeit".toCharArray());
String alias = "edotto";

Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "changeit".toCharArray());

if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
    // Get certificate of public key
    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

    // Get public key
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

    // Return a key pair
    new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
}


AttributiAutorizzativi attributi = new AttributiAutorizzativi("getElencoPAIDomiciliare",
        "HEALTHNETBR","RIS000282");



ElencoPAIDomiciliareRequest criterioRicerca = new ElencoPAIDomiciliareRequest();
criterioRicerca.setDataInizioRiferimento("01/12/2000");
criterioRicerca.setDataFineRiferimento("01/07/2015");
criterioRicerca.setCodiceNazionale("160114");
criterioRicerca.setTipologiaAssistenzaAutorizzata(0);
criterioRicerca.setDistretto("53");


GetElencoPAIDomiciliare request = new GetElencoPAIDomiciliare();
request.setCriteriRicerca(criterioRicerca);

//

PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService service = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeServiceLocator();
PianoAssistenzialeResidenziale stub = service.getPianoAssistenzialeResidenzialePort();


PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeProxy client = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeProxy();
client.getElencoPAIDomiciliare(request, attributi);

System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Try to add security header...

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your client with Axis2 you can use [Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/), if not, you can add the wsse headers creating and adding the elements manually

```
SOAPHeader header = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
header.addChildElement(securitySOAPElement);
```

or you can use [WSS4J](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/) (best choice)

Comment: I have edit my question, can you tell me how can I change my code?

Comment: I can't, sorry, that work is yours, I tried to guide you to do the best choice for adding security to your client, do a choice, read the docs and try your implementation, then we could help you.